# Task Runner Explorer is not present in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I can't see the Task Runner Explorer option in 'View' -> 'Other Window' menu, I can't figure out why I can't see it, I have Visual Studio Community installed on another computer and the option is visible.

Here is a screenshot :

[image: View menu]

Anyone have an idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in VS 2015 but may have shipped in update so make sure your on the newest version, there is also an extension in the visual studio gallery that's supposed to be for 2013 but should work for 2015 as well.

Edit: for 2015 may be in web extensions package.